# Cannot wrap RelativeLayout but subclassing isn't appropriate

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a subclass of `View` in Android which shows a series of `ShapeDrawables`. These shape drawables respond to user events. Internally, my `View` has a programmatically created `RelativeLayout` member variable which is used to layout the `Drawables`. I had intended to treat my `View` as a wrapper for the `RelativeLayout` by calling the `RelativeLayout's` `onDraw`/`onMeasure`/etc methods in my `onDraw`/`onMeasure`/etc methods. As it turns out, these methods are protected so I cannot access them.

How should I proceed? I'm hesitant to subclass `RelativeLayout` since my view isn't really a `RelativeLayout` and therefore it fails the "IS A" test. I just need to hook the methods from `RelativeLayout` into my draw/measure etc methods, is there another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extends the RelativeLayout to handle the onDraw/onMeasure yourself. as for the "Is A" principle, you can extend the **[ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)** instead. the **ViewGroup** is the super class of **RelativeLayout**

Comment: The problem with extending a view group though is that the ViewGroup class defines methods which aren't appropriate for my view. It shouldn't be able to have views added or removed etc, and it isn't a generic viewgroup to contain arbitrary view children. The only reason a relative layout is involved at all is because it helps me set some things out internally. I don't want any of the public methods ViewGroup defines to be able to modify my View.

Comment: So, there is no problem in extending the RelativeLayout, this won't validate the "Is A" principle